# How to extract a specific field of all sub documents in MongoDB using aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection `customer` with the following structure.

Now I'm trying to extract the value of `tier` field of all sub documents of `tier_and_details` into an array.

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ca4bbcea2dd94ee58162a69"),
  "username": "valenciajennifer",
  "name": "Lindsay Cowan",
  "address": "Unit 1047 Box 4089\nDPO AA 57348",
  "birthdate": ISODate("1994-02-19T23:46:27Z"),
  "email": "cooperalexis@hotmail.com",
  "accounts": [
    116508
  ],
  "tier_and_details": {
    "c06d340a4bad42c59e3b6665571d2907": {
      "tier": "Platinum",
      "benefits": [
        "dedicated account representative"
      ],
      "active": true,
      "id": "c06d340a4bad42c59e3b6665571d2907"
    },
    "5d6a79083c26402bbef823a55d2f4208": {
      "tier": "Bronze",
      "benefits": [
        "car rental insurance",
        "concierge services"
      ],
      "active": true,
      "id": "5d6a79083c26402bbef823a55d2f4208"
    },
    "b754ec2d455143bcb0f0d7bd46de6e06": {
      "tier": "Gold",
      "benefits": [
        "airline lounge access"
      ],
      "active": true,
      "id": "b754ec2d455143bcb0f0d7bd46de6e06"
    }
  }
}
```

The result shoud be like

```
["Platinum","Bronze","Gold"]
```

How to implement it with Mongo aggregation pipeline?
The question is somewhat like [MongoDB: Aggregate values of all fields of a specific subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840825/mongodb-aggregate-values-of-all-fields-of-a-specific-subdocument), while Map-Reduce framework in the answer has now been deprecated.

Comment: Having dynamic field names like in your example is an anti-pattern for MongoDB, you should review your data design.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I up-voted your comment because it is sound advice and I agree with it but I also recognise that document anywhere. It's from a sample MongoDB Atlas `customers.json` file. OP has no control over it's data design.

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {data: {$objectToArray: "$tier_and_details"}}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, data: "$data.v.tier"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PG2Lh4T1Edy)

Another option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {$map: {
          input: {$objectToArray: "$tier_and_details"},
          in: "$$this.v.tier"
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QrGjDdf8d_c)